# Allow a collaborator to deploy a Git repository they do not own to Azure?

Tags: git, azure, github

Is there any way on Azure to allow a collaborator to setup source-control deployment on a repository they do not own?

It can really slow things down when you need to wait for the owner to be free to set this up, especially when setting up multiple apps for multiple branches etc.

If collaborators could do this too it would be really useful, is this possible?

I think the only way would be for everybody to fork the codebase, and then they would own that fork and could deploy to Azure. Then using pull reqeusts to merge code. Would this be the correct approach?

The main problem with this would be that you could only hook an azure website up to one persons branch, so may spend a lot of time disconnecting from and reconnecting to Github when different users need to deploy.

Does anybody have a good solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want multiple people that have access to azure to be able to publish your repository you could just add the git repo from azure websites as a remote in your devs repositories:

```
git remote add azure https://<username>@<sitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/<reponame>.git
```

And then all devs would be able to deploy by doing:

```
git push azure master
```

[Detailed instructions on setting up the "build in" continious deployment is here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/)